# How To Get Last Inserted Row From Table Using LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Employee

Empid | EmployeeName
1-------------Ron
2------------John

Department

Depid | DepartmentName | Status| Empid
1---------------Account--------- 1---------1
2---------------HR----------------1---------1
 
3---------------Finance----------1---------2
 
4---------------Design-----------1---------2

Here I have two table Employee and Department. One employee can be in different department such as empid = 1 in two department i.e account and hr similarly empid = 2 in two department i.e finance and design .
 Now, for example since empid = 1 is inserted in depid = 1 and depid = 2 but I am tryingto get depid = 2 which is last inserted row for empid = 2.Similarly, for empid = 2 last row of department which is depid = 4.
Now, the problem is that my LINQ join doesnot give the required output.
Since i am very much new to Linq, help will be highly appreciated.Thank you
Below is my LINQ Join

```
 var empDepList = (from D in db.Department.Where(x => x.Status == 1)
                   join E in db.Employee on D.Empid equals E.Empid
                   select new
                   {
                     D.DepartmentName, E.EmployeeName
                   }).ToList();
```

Comment: How by your data (which column) can you tell what was inserted last?

Comment: @GiladGreen DepId = 2 and DepId = 4 .

Comment: But how would you know that if not by the order in the table?

Comment: You should ignore the LINQ for now. Go to your SSMS or whatever tool you use and run your queries from there.  If you can get your output from there then you can translate it to code. If you look at the previous comments, everyone, in essence, is telling you to review your data model. Are you trying to get the current department an employee is on?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Better edit your question, it is hard to read and understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

If the `Employee.Empid` is the primary key, a crude way to do this could be as follows:

```
var empDepList = 
    (from D in db.Department
     join E in db.Employee on D.Empid equals E.Empid
     where D.Status == 1
     orderby E.Empid, D.Depid descending
     select new {
         D.DepartmentName, E.EmployeeName
     }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Sir how can i return the data in list using Linq suggested by you

Comment: Did you not only want the 'last insert row'? Maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: This query return Only One Value Can't Return to list

Answer (score 0):

try Code :

You have Used Group by or Subquery Used achieved your result;

```
var empDepList = (from E in db.Employee                  
               select {
                DepartmentName= db.Department.where(c=>c.status==1 && c.Empid==E.Empid).LastOrDefault()==null?"":db.Department.where(c=>c.status==1 && c.Empid==E.Empid).LastOrDefault().DepartmentName,
                EmployeeName= E.EmployeeName
               }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:
**var lastSequence = context.Periods.OrderByDescending(p => p.Id).FirstOrDefault().Sequence;**
It order the Periods Table by Id descending and take only one record, then I select the column Sequence of my Periods Table, In this case this returns me **11**
[image: Periods Table]

Answer (score 0):

```
context.MyTable.Find(context.MyTable.Max(p => p.Id));
```